# How to recreate hardware mirror RAID with bigger drives?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, ahci

I had a RAID 1 mirrored array composed of 2 x 500GB HDDs connected to my Gigabyte Z590 motherboard.

I was running out of space, so I cloned one of the drives with Clonezilla to a 1TB drive.

On that new drive, I created partitions and extended the data partition to include the unassigned 500GB.

I could boot to my OS, so I went ahead and cloned that 1TB drive to another 1TB drive and attempted to recreate the RAID 1 array with those drives.

Problem was that my 1TB drives were emptied by the BIOS, so I want to know how to recreate my RAID 1 array.

In my BIOS, I did the following when trying to recreate the RAID:

- Settings → I/O ports → Sata and RST configuration → Sata mode selection = AHCI
- Settings → Intel (r) rapid storage technology → Create RAID volume → Raid level 1 (mirror) → I selected both 1 TB drives → Create

Comment: You cloned the clone of a single disk in a mirror RAID? Why? You should have clone 1:1 then expanded the storage of the entire RAID

Comment: Typically you can take a single HDD with data, and another HDD that is unformatted and create a RAID 1 array.  The RAID controller will create the mirror for you.